# PHP warning on include_once and admin::isSession() command like Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'admin' not found

Tags: php, android, html

I am working to create my admin panel for my application but I have face some problem-related PHP command in

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/core/init.inc.php");
```

and

```
  if (admin::isSession()) {

    header("Location: admin.php");
}
```

line

**Got Three Error in index.php**

> Warning: include_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/core/init.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBPANEL\index.php.
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:/xampp/htdocs/core/init.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBPANEL\index.php
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'admin' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBPANEL\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBPANEL\index.php

**My index.php Code**

```
<?php


include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/core/init.inc.php");


    if (admin::isSession()) {

    header("Location: admin.php");
}


$css_files = array();
$page_title = "Dummy Code";

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/common/header.inc.php");
```

?>

```
<div style="text-align: center;font-size: 56px; font-weight: 200; margin: 140px 0;">

    <div style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <a href="<?php echo GOOGLE_PLAY_LINK; ?>" rel="nofollow">
            <img src="/img/googleplay.png">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 40px; font-size: 22px;">
        <a style="color: #3A6DA5" href="/admin/login.php">Go to admin panel -></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Help me to resolves this problem!

Comment: Is there a class named "admin"? I would assume your class would be within this header.inc.php file? I would first try to resolve your failing include. Your file header.inc.php seems not to be found. try to `print $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/common/header.inc.php"` at the beginning of your index.php file. Then check if the full path actually leads to your file.

Comment: @natheriel Thank you for your feedback. I try to print `include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/common/header.inc.php");` but same problem

Comment: You have only to print `print $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/common/header.inc.‌​php";` Do not use the "include_once" within your print, as this will not give you any data. As it runs into a fatal error later you may have to add a "die" too. Make sure following is at the first line of code after your <?php in your index.php file: `print $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/common/header.inc.php"; die();` This will give you the output you need to check your include.

Comment: @natheriel Can you post  screenshot of code please because Now my output is https://ibb.co/d2h5M5.

Comment: Any screenshot from my site will not help you, as I do not have the same environment as you. But now you know that the include your file at "C:\xampp\htdocs\common\header.inc.php". Is your header.inc.php File located there if you check this by hand? I guess there is a folder missing. According to your given errors your files are located at C:\xampp\htdocs\WEBPANEL. So your include will most likely be: `include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/WEBPANEL/core/init.inc.php");`. Change your include to that, then remove my previous given line with the "die()".

Comment: But same problem I'm facing :(

Comment: @natheriel ***But thanks, It's very helpful for my project***